# Как можно скачать и распаковать zip-архив с удаленного сайта программно?

Tags: wordpress, node.js, gulp, npm

Есть сборка gulp,в которую хочу добавить автоматическую подготовку темы wordpress. Для этого мне нужно скачать и распаковать архив с wordpress, а также архив с темой с сайта underscores.me. Конечно, я могу сделать это вручную, но хочется именно автоматизировать процесс. Возможно ли это?

Comment: https://wp-cli.org/ ?

Comment: Надо делать это не из gulp, а из bash, в котором доставть и распаковывать, а уж gulp запускать потом из того же bash файла.